# Moose & isa ArrayRef

Tags: perl, moose

I am trying to use Moose with Moose::Meta::Attribute::Native::Trait::Array but it looks like ArrayRef helper doesn't work for me. Bellow is my code which returns

`Can't call method "add_item" on unblessed reference at bug.pl line 42.`

I use Moose 2.0007 and Perl v5.10.1. Moose::Autobox is installed.
I would appreciate any suggestion.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

package CycleSplit;
use Moose;
has 'name'=>(isa=>'Str', is=>'rw');
has 'start'=>(isa=>'Num', is=>'rw');
has 'length'=>(isa=>'Num', is=>'rw');
1;

package Cycle;
use Moose;
my @empty=();
has 'name' => (isa => 'Str', is => 'rw');
has 'splits' => (
    traits  => ['Array'],
    isa=>'ArrayRef[CycleSplit]',
    is => 'rw',
    default=>sub { [] },
    handles=>{
        add_item=>'push',
    },
);


no Moose;
1;

package Main;

sub Main {
    my $cyc=Cycle->new();
    $cyc->name("Days of week");

    for my $i (1..7) {
        my $spl=CycleSplit->new();
        $spl->name("Day $i");
        $spl->start($i/7-(1/7));
        $spl->length(1/7);
        $cyc->splits->add_item($spl);
    }

    my $text='';
    foreach my $spl ($cyc->splits) {
        $text.=$spl->name." ";
    }

    print $text;
}

Main;
```

Comment: Not a moose expert, but try:  $cyc->add_item($spl);

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`handles` add method to class itself, not to the attribute. Another problem is that `splits` attribute is still arrayref, so you need dereference in seconds `foreach`. Corrected code is as follows:

```
sub Main {
    my $cyc=Cycle->new();
    $cyc->name("Days of week");

    for my $i (1..7) {
        my $spl=CycleSplit->new();
        $spl->name("Day $i");
        $spl->start($i/7-(1/7));
        $spl->length(1/7);
        $cyc->add_item($spl);               # removed splits
    }

    my $text='';
    foreach my $spl (@{ $cyc->splits }) {   # added array dereference
        $text.=$spl->name." ";
    }

    print $text;
}
```

Comment: Note that you can say `handles => { ..., items => 'elements' }` and get a list via `items` directly without dereferencing. I prefer this variant since it doesn't let people sneak values past the validation.

Comment: @phaylon: agreed; I never use the `is => ` option for native trait attributes, so the only access is via the delegated methods.

Comment: @Ether - thanks for the tip. I always use delegated methods, but leaving out `is` did not occur to me.